# How can i disable a button if the Status='1'? (1=Confirmed)

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $vehiclestatus = $row['Status'];
    if ($vehiclestatus == '1'){
        echo "<h1>reserved</h1>";
    }
?>
```

//the Status belongs to the `tblbooking` database
//below is the button I want to disable

```
<a href="vehical-details.php?vhid=
    <?php echo htmlentities($result->id);? >" 
        class="btn">Request this Vehicle <span class="angle_arrow">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using an anchor tag, instead of a button, you can't use the `disabled` attribute. You can however do something like this

```
<a <?php if($row['Status'] == 1) echo "href='vehical-details.php?vhid=" . htmlentities($result->id) . "'"; ?> class="btn">Request this Vehicle <span class="angle_arrow"><i 
class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
```

This will only give the tag the `href` attribute if the status is 1. Not having the `href` is essentially the same as being disabled.

Comment: it's not working, it disabled all the vehicles for reservation.
PS. i want to change the "Request this Vehicle" to "Reserved" if Status=1